# Scala: How to check if at least one of the fields of a class is defined?

Tags: scala, reflection, field, option-type

I have a class which has several optional fields as given below:

```
class Container(f1: Option[String] = None,
                f2: Option[Boolean] = None,
                f3: Option[Int] = None,
                f4: Option[String] = None
                // ... 30 other fields which is unfortunate/terrible and
                // cannot be changed at the moment
                 ) {
  def hasAtleastOneDefinedField: Boolean = {
    this.f1.isDefined ||
      this.f2.isDefined ||
      this.f3.isDefined ||
      this.f4.isDefined
    // this is too-much of boilerplate
  }

  // This is something along the lines of what I want
  def hasAtleastOneDefinedField2: Boolean = {
    // this.getAllDeclaredFields.find(field => field.value.isDefined)
    ???
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same without using reflection ?

Comment: Reflection is not so bad. Start with something like: `weakTypeOf[Container].typeSymbol.asClass.typeSignature.members` - you will get symbols of all fields (+ something more you should to filter out). Then recreate fields with macros as a list of values and check that there exists nonEmpty field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how much this saves you, but:

```
  val hasAtLeastOneDefinedField = List(f1, f2, f3, ..., f35).exists { _.isDefined }
```

Don't think there is another way short of reflection/macros.

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought, but depending on your intended use, there may be design patterns worth considering that could make your intent clearer.

If, for example, you are trying to determine if you have sufficient data to construct something, then one option is the builder pattern, eg.:

```
object ContainerBuilder() {
  def fromF1(f1: F1) = Container(f1 = Some(f1))
  def fromF2(f2: F2) = Container(f2 = Some(f2))
  ...
}
```

if you only allow Container instances to be built this way (eg. the Container class' constructor is only visible to the builder), you can be sure that they will have precisely one field set (there are various ways to extend this to produce Containers with multiple fields set, eg see below).

This can be extended to, for example, ensure two, three, ..., all fields are set before a Container is created. Eg.:

```
class ContainerBuilder(f1: Option[String] = None,
                       f2: Option[Boolean] = None,
                       f3: Option[Int] = None,
                       f4: Option[String] = None,
                       ...,
                       fieldsSet = 0) {
  // return a copy of this ContainerBuilder - holding any fields already set - 
  // with f1 now set, and the count of set fields incremented: 
  def fromF1(f1: F1) = copy(f1 = Some(f1), fieldsSet = fieldsSet + 1)

  // Likewise but setting the f2 field:
  def fromF2(f2: F2) = copy(f2 = Some(f2), fieldsSet = fieldsSet + 1)

  ...

  def build = if (readyToBuild) Container(f1,f2,...) else ... // for 'unready' cases, you can throw an exception, or change build to return an Option[Container], or whatever.

  def readyToBuild = fieldsSet > 2 // Ensures at least 3 fields set - change to whatever criteria you need.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few more ways to express this:

```
val o1 = None
val o2 = None
val o3 = Option("o")

o1.orElse(o2).orElse(o3).isDefined

List(o1, o2, o3).flatten.nonEmpty
```